# listening to a Bluetooth LE device in the background

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, background-service

I am developing an application that requires Bluetooth LE support. In any case, I need to trigger an activity in my app after the device has sent a string. The problem is that this has to be in every case - even if the app is minimised or the phone is asleep. There are several solutions on the web for background activity, but I want to ask how can this be solved so that it works reliably and I can be sure that the action will occur? Thank you for your suggestions for solutions to the problem.

Comment: You may be able to use `JobScheduler` if you are targeting Android Api 23 or greater. If not, `IntentService` may do the trick. More details here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/starting-background-services

Comment: Background services have time limitations as of Android 12. If you wanna make a service that needs to interact with the user even its activity is closed then you must go with [Foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) + notification pattern. Android 12 will not kill your foreground service if you display a notification within 10 seconds right after starting the foreground service.